# NetBeans can't find classes in imported jdde pretty-tools jar file

Tags: java, netbeans, import, jar, dde

I want to use the DDE with Java and after some research I decided to go with http://jdde.pretty-tools.com/

My programming platform for this project is NetBeans.

However, I have encountered a slight problem. I have imported the jar file as it supposedly should be done, i.e. right click package > Properties > Libraries > Add JAR/Folder. I also tried creating a new library and adding the jar file through this way. In both cases I have manged to import the jar and in the Libraries folder I can see the jar and the source files in that jar, which means that until this point everything went correctly. The problem starts when I try to import the package into my source file i.e.:

```
import com.pretty_tools.dde.client.*;
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DDEClientConversation conversation = new DDEClientConversation();
}
```

The result of this is that DDEClientConversation is marked as error with a message 'cannot find symbol'. I am considering that there might be a problem with the pretty tools jar file in some weird way, since when I import a different jar from a different package all works fine.

Comment: JDDE 2.0.1 published by [pretty-tools.com](http://www.pretty-tools.com) does not contain *.java files inside JAR anymore, therefore original problem will not appear anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this satisfies the moderators...

I have communicated with the pretty-tools author (Alexander Kozlov) who cannot validate the library compatibility with the NetBeans IDE. I have, however, had success using the jDDE library from http://code.google.com/p/jdde/ in the NetBeans 7.0.1 IDE.

Comment: It worked, thanks. Must have been some version incompatibility.

Comment: I have one more thing to note. The above way works, however if any one ever needs to get NetBeans 7.0.1 IDE working with the Pretty Tools from [http://jdde.pretty-tools.com/](http://jdde.pretty-tools.com/) version, I have solved it by unpacking the jar and adding the file created to the Libraries section.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the underscore in the package name was causing troubles.
See http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html

Rename the jar as zip and check the paths. Probably pretty-tools (with a minus) is the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

The paths are good. Another solution is to repack the jar with the compiled .class files only.

For some reason, NetBeans does not seem to like that the .java source files are packaged up with the compiled .class files. If you unpack the jar using any zip archiver, delete the .java source files, and repack as a jar as a zip and change the extension to .jar. Add this jar to your Library and it works great.